# How to pass value from JSP to Struts java code dynamically

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc, struts2, ognl

I am working on Struts. I have a JSP login page through which user will submit his data. After that if anyone want to search his data he have to enter his `id`. I want this `id` to be entered dynamically.

This `id` will be passed to a Java page. I am using JDBC. How to write the query and set string function?

**Here is my Java code:**

```
// package com.javatpoint;  
import java.sql.*;  
import java.util.ArrayList;  
  
public class Display {  
ArrayList<User> list=new ArrayList<User>();  
  User user= new User();
public ArrayList<User> getList() {  
    return list;  
}  
public void setList(ArrayList<User> list) {  
    this.list = list;  
}  
public String execute(){  
 try{  
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","Ericsson@123");  
              
  PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from  STRUTSUSER where id=?");
  ps.setInt(0,user.getId());  
  ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();  
  
  while(rs.next()){  
   User user=new User();  
   user.setId(rs.getInt(1));  
   user.setName(rs.getString(2));  
   user.setPassword(rs.getString(3));  
   user.setEmail(rs.getString(4));  
   list.add(user);  
  } 
   
      
 }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}  
          
 return "succes";
}  
}
```

**`struts.xml`:**

```xml
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD   
     Struts Configuration 2.1//EN"   
 "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">  
<struts>  

 <package name="anbc" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">  
  <action name="display" class="com.javatpoint.Display">  
    <result name="success">display.jsp</result>  
  </action>  
 </package> 
 <package name="abc" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">  
  <action name="login" class="com.javatpoint.Register">  
    <result name="success">welcome.jsp</result>  
  </action>  
 </package>  

</struts>
```

Comment: Post `struts.xml`, and what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `User` object for the model, but not use model driven action, then to get user by the `id` you should use `user.id` parameter in the request. You should also use a getter for the model

```
public User getUser(){
  return user;
}
```

When the action is called it will set the parameter to the user object. Now to set it as parameter in the query

```
ps.setInt(1, user.getId()); //parameters are counted from 1..n
```

See details of using [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

You should return `Action.SUCCESS` result, and there's no need to name a result `"success"` because it's default name.

```
return Action.SUCCESS;
```

If you are passing user id as a parameter then you won't get more than one object in the list, but to bind a list in JSP you can use `iterator` tag

```
<s:iterator value="list">
  ID: <s:property value="id"/><br>
  Name: <s:property value="name"/><br>
  Email: <s:property value="email"/><br>      
</s:iterator>
```

The properties should have corresponding getters in the `User` object.

Loading classes and opening connection (that you forgot to close) in action is bad. To get a `Connection` object you can configure and use a data source. See for examples [How JSF is inegrated with JDBC](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-jdbc-integration-example/) and [How to create MySQL database connection in `web.xml` of Apache Tomcat using Struts 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26078671/573032).