# Why is it that this java code is not able to retrieve something by a given integer?

Tags: java, mysql, web-services

I'm trying to write this program to retrieve a path / multiple paths in MySQL by a given integer variable titled "NumOfServings". I can't seem to get it to work for some reason:

```
@Path("/recipes/{NumOfServings}")
@GET
@Produces("text/plain")
public String getRecipesByServingSize(@PathParam("NumOfServings") String ourServingSize) throws SQLException,  

ClassNotFoundException
{
    int checkServingSize = 0;
    try {
        checkServingSize = Integer.parseInt(ourServingSize);
    }catch (NumberFormatException FAIL) {
        checkServingSize = 1;
    }
    String connectStr="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fooddb";
    String username="root";
    String password="csci330pass";
    String driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    Class.forName(driver);
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectStr, username, password);
    String sql = "Enter in a Recipe ID from Recipe database, WHERE ID = ?";
    PreparedStatement prepStmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    if (ourServingSize >= 6)
    {
        prepStmt.setInt(1, ourServingSize);
        ResultSet rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();
    }
    else
    {
        prepStmt.setInt(0, ourServingSize);
        ResultSet rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();
    }
    String result = "";
    while (rs.next()) 
    {
        int recipeID3 = rs.getInt("RecipeID");
        String recipeName3 = rs.getString("RecipeName");
        String recipeType3 = rs.getString("RecipeType");
        String instructions3 = rs.getString("Instructions");
        int amtServings3 = rs.getInt("NumOfServings");
        int timeMinutes3 = rs.getInt("TotalTimeInMinutes");
        result += "ID: "+recipeID3+ "\n" +
                "Name: "+recipeName3+ "\n" +
                "Type: "+recipeType3+ "\n" +
                "Instructions: "+instructions3+ "\n" +
                "Total Servings: "+amtServings3+ "\n" +
                "Total Time: "+timeMinutes3+ "\n" + "\n";
    }
    return result;
}
```

I've tried If - Else statements and a while loop, but I can't get it to work without spewing a series of errors at me. What exactly is wrong with this code? What exactly is missing that is causing me these errors?

Comment: `@PathParam("RecipeIDhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/26712370/how-to-pass-value-from-jsp-to-struts-java-code-dynamically") String ourServingSize`?? Should be `@PathParam("NumOfServings")`

Comment: I don't know how that happened, but thanks for that. I've already corrected the issue with that typo.

Comment: `String sql = "Enter in a Recipe ID from Recipe database, WHERE ID = ?";` Uhm, is this MySQL? (Hint: no.)

Comment: Yes, sorry - this is partially Java. I was going to get that to say "Enter in a Serving Size from Recipe Database to retrieve you data." I think that makes the most sense for what I'm trying to do here.

Comment: If you are running it, it will obviuosly throw an error. Enter the query you are using. Also add your stack trace!

Comment: NumOfServings is my query. Got it. It should look something like this, I'm sure...  String sql = "Enter in a Recipe ID from Recipe database, WHERE NumOfServings = ?";

Comment: That's still not an [SQL query.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) It should be something like `SELECT * FROM Recipe WHERE NumOfServings = ?`, but mine is a wild guess...

Answer (score 0):

`prepStmt.setInt(0, ourServingSize);` is wrong

You should always use `prepStmt.setInt(1, ourServingSize);`, since 1 is the index of the first parameter.

Comment: I want this code to only return something when the Integer "NumOfServings" is only greater than or equal to 6. Otherwise, the process doesn't go through. That' what I'm trying to fix here with my code.

Comment: @user2891351 But you are executing the query either way. If you don't want to do anything when ourServingSize < 6, you put put that condition at the beginning of your method.

Comment: That's good to know, but I don't know how to do that, unfortunately... As it is, I am trying to get this to respond to some index.html code properly. Do you happen to know what I have to do here, or is there some place I can look this up for myself so I can fix this issue ASAP? Thank you.