# Struts 2 ~ Best place to initiate a socket?

Tags: java, sockets, struts2

I have a Struts 2 web application.  On application startup I need to open a socket to a data source, stream the data in and store it in objects which will probably be held in the ServletContext.

I could initialize the socket in the contextInitialized(...) method the of the ServletContextListener; however, I am wondering if this is the best place to do this.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's largely irrelevant where it lives, but that's certainly a canonical place to put things that need to happen at startup (and shutdown). "Best" is somewhat subjective, and it depends on what else you're using in your app (e.g., Spring).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26078671/573032